# PayPal IPN notify and success URL params

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm implementing a simple Buy Now button and I'm using IPN (not PDT) to verify the transaction.

A thing that bugs me is that I don't understand how come only after I set the `notify_url` field to the button I also get the transaction variables to the success URL, as GET params. It would seem normal to be the other way around.

Since the user could or could not choose to "return to the merchant's website" there's not way I should rely on that data. It does however seem to be identical to the one sent to the notify URL.

Some clarification would help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know what you mean, after the user has finished paying and chooses to return to the sellers website (button in paypal page) they are redirected to your thankyou page.

I don't think it used to do this back in 2009 but now paypal will issue the redirect with all sorts of parameters in the url query string.

I'm just ignoring this information and relying on the backend IPN post which is verifiable by paypal

Answer (score 0):

In my previous experience with IPN, I defined the location of the notify URL in the control panel.  Once the payment is processed, PayPal sends a POST notification to this URL independent of any user behavior.

In any case, even if you define the notify_url parameter in the button, I believe PayPal will still send the payment notification seperate from the user behavior - they spawn a new process to send the data.  As to why they are using a GET rather than a POST, that is odd behavior.  However, in your IPN script you should still have logic that verifies the call with PayPal before you continue processing.